# Best practice to access property in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I comes from Java background and working first time on Kotlin. For most of the people it will be basic question, but it may help people who start working first time on Kotlin and comes from Java background

So, let say I have listadapter and I want to set list of item in that. I have two options now.

1) create a private property which stores list of items and then create a setter for it, which set the list and call notifydatasetChanged()

2) create a property with set property function and then access like instance.property

Which will be better option in Kotlin out of above two options.

Comment: why this question is down voted. I comes from java and asking for best practice in kotlin. what is wrong in that. mention reason also if you are down voting.

Comment: Ideally, you don't use getters and setters in Kotlin. I'd say you just use `classInstance.propertyName`. To assign a value to it, you can do something like this:
`listadapter.items = itemsFromServer` and then either call `notifyDataSetChanged()` or setAdapter() whichever is applicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A property in *Kotlin* is nothing else then a getter and setter for a value. If you don't want to provide a getter, you have to use a `fun setData(data: List)`.

Otherwise it's also possible to handle everything with the property

```
var data = listOf()
        set(data: List) {
            field = data
            notifydatasetChanged()
        }
```

But eventually it's even better to use an implementation with `DiffUtil`.

Comment: it is just to clarify , so when we use DiffUtil we should use  property  or other way round.

Comment: @Anil you should use whatever you deem best for it. `DiffUtil` just replaces `notifydatasetChanged()` in a way. But the main calculations you should do on the background. And you don't necessary need to call `notifydatasetChanged()` from within the adapter.